# How can I dye my hardwood inside deeply so I can laminate something like this?

Tags: hardwood

I found someone used the recycling skateboard for making great creations. So just what kind of oil or paint I can use for dyeing on hardwood **inside** deeply(for laminating)!? Not just coated on the surface.

[image: An ax with a wooden handle. The handle appears to be composed of strips of differently-colored wood]

Comment: I think this question should be revised to ask specifically about dyeing veneer, since that's what was done here.

Comment: Note that the handle is itself then glued up from several separately laminated pieces (or different chunks of a single laminated slab), since the "grain" runs in at least two different directions.

Answer (score 6):

The handle in your photo is laminated, each colored strip was individually dyed before the lamination process.

It's been 40 years since I dyed wood but the process worked well. I made my own purfling and binding for my guitars. I believe the dyes I used analine dyes in  powder form that dissolves in water. The other thing I did was to soak overnight in very hot water. I had a galvinized trough that I used for this. The wood I used for this was maple, birch would be good as well. You want a wood without open pores.

This can be a messy process, especially if you want several colors. You might also check to see whether what you want is commercially available. One place to look are luthier suppliers such as LMI and StewMac.

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about it, but I think that commercial veneer dying also involves putting the whole setup under a vacuum.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232. Curious, I'd think high pressure would be more efficacious as with pressure treated lumber.

Comment: @bpedit Both vacuum and high pressure have the same net effect. One draws the dye into the wood as air is sucked out of the surface, the other forces the dye into the wood by displacing some of the moisture. I believe some dyeing uses both techniques in fact, vacuum first and then pressure.

Comment: HI @bpedit, can you share more about the step of "soak overnight in very hot water"? Did you dye in hot water or that was just something process?

Comment: @bard. Apologies, its been 35 years. I believe I had this trough on the stove for hours and may have then kept it a hot plate overnight or multiple nights. The wood was maple, 3-4 mm thick, which was dyed all the way through. After drying it was sanded then milled to meet my needs. Again, I highly recommend checking for commercial sources. I doubt everyoneI see using this colorful lamination technique is dying their own wood.

Comment: @bard. Search "thick dyed veneer", many links to investigate.

Answer (score 3):

Wood dyes can be very expensive or very reasonable. Check out suppliers such Transfast wood dyes which come in a powdered form and can be tinted darker by adding more dye to the liquid base.  You can use water but that will often raise the grain. I use rubbing alcohol from the big box which does not affect the grain.  It goes on fairly evenly, dries fast and does not raise the grain.  Other answers point out that your example uses veneer layers which are thin and can absorb the dye through the entire depth of the layer.  IF you use thicker pieces, the dye will not penetrate all the way through.  You may have to run a few experiments including rubbing on the dye and fully soaking the wood to find out the best technique for full color penetration.

Answer (score 2):

Well that is not dyed hardwood, it is laminated (layered) pieces of wood which are brightly colored individually then glued together.  Afterwards you sand or plane the surface and get the contrast like that.

You can also buy blocks which are already brightly colored.  I think usually people will turn them.  Sometimes they put layers of acrylic in as well to add more bold colors.

Comment: ok, I knew it's laminated, but what I am asking is how to dye it by myself so I can maybe laminate one since I don't know how to get one recycling skateboard like it.

Answer (score 2):

There are sources where you can buy them pre-dyed which would probably be at least worth looking into as a reference point, if not eliminate the need to dye them yourself.

[Dyed-Veneers](http://www.dyed-veneer.com/dyed_veneers.aspx)

[Woodcraft](https://www.woodcraft.com/products/dyed-primary-colors-of-veneer-3-sq-foot-pack?gclid=CI30k_nAj9ICFYM9gQodaeAATg)